# Use the progress report to tweak my performance in ParallelComputation

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

I run a parallel sum over 4 indices with `2x8x152x8=19456` elements.

I get a progress report that looks like this

```
Parallel Sum
########.................
Results 0/2 evaluations of 1 items each (12 kernels)
Times elapses: 02m 16s, remaining: 02m 16s, ETA: THU 20 Oct 2022 13:29:41
```

I'm mainly interested in the results line. How can I use it to tune my performance? From what I've seen on `htop` not all 12 cores seem to be running at 100%. In fact, only one runs at 100% and maybe 3-4 run at ~40%. Does this mean my parallelization is not running at full potential?

When I manually set `Method->"CoarsestGrained"` I get `10/12 evaluations of 1 items each (12 kernels)`. Is this better? The overall computation time is quite similar where it is 2 total or 12 total evaluations.

**How can I use the Progress report to tweak my performance and what values should I strive for?**

Comment: Is it possible to share an example?

Comment: It could be that the bottleneck is not CPU power, but available memory, storage access, information transfer between kernels or a combination of these and others. More cores is not necessarily better.